# Can someone help me identify what type of spider or insect builds a green nest that is black an gold

Tags: species-identification

I had the same thing a spider like creature that was black and gold the size of a dime that was building a green sack like web that stuck to the windshield. Location south texas winter, any supspects?

Comment: The green web will be a nest for eggs. We would need high quality photos from several perspectives of the spider to ID.